# Can I Get The Object Name in A Loop? - Swift 2

Tags: arrays, loops, object, swift2

I've written this loop. But, I'm wondering if I can do without the name property and just reference the name of the object?

```
class Param {
    var name = ""
    var value = 0.0
    var skip = -1
}

let depth = Param()
depth.name = "depth"
let tankPressure = Param()
tankPressure.name = "tankPressure"
let time = Param()
time.name = "time"
let tankCapacity = Param()
tankCapacity.name = "tankCapacity"
let litresPerMinute = Param()
litresPerMinute.name = "litresPerMinute"
let params = [depth, tankPressure, time, tankCapacity, litresPerMinute]

for param in params {
    let outlet = "\(param.name)Outlet.text!"
    print(outlet)
}
```